# why handlemessage not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

i have a problem with handler in android, i don't understand not display result, this's code:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText nhap;
private Button btTinh;
private Button btHuy;
private TextView kq;
private ProgressDialog progress;
private Handler handle = new Handler();
private int count = 0;
private String s = "";
private long n;
```

handlemessage:

```
Handler mhandle = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        kq.setText(msg.obj.toString());
    }
};
```

onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    nhap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nhap);
    btTinh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btTinh);
    btHuy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btHuy);
    kq = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kq);
    btTinh.setOnClickListener(this);
    btHuy.setOnClickListener(this);
}   

public boolean checkPrime(long n) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

outprime:

```
public void outPrime(long t) {
    // String s="";
    progress.setCancelable(true);
    progress.setMessage("File downloading ...");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progress.setProgress(0);
    progress.setMax(Integer.parseInt(nhap.getText().toString()));
    progress.show();
    n = t;
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                count = i;
                if (checkPrime(i))
                    s = s + i + " ";
                handle.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        progress.setProgress(count);
                    }
                });


            }
            if (count == n - 1) {
                progress.dismiss();
                Message msg = handle.obtainMessage(1, (String)s);
                handle.sendMessage(msg);
            }

        }
    }.start();


}
```

onclick:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btTinh:
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        outPrime(Long.parseLong(nhap.getText().toString()));
        break;
    case R.id.btHuy:
        nhap.setText("");
        break;
    }
}}
```

this's handlemessage:

```
Handler mhandle = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        kq.setText(msg.obj.toString());
    }
};
```

i don't understand handlemessage don't return value, "kq.setText(msg.obj.toString());" don't display to screen, sorry because my english not good

Comment: how can `handleMessage` return value when the return type is `void`

Comment: oh no, it's mean " kq.setText(msg.obj.toString());" don't display to screen

Comment: sr, i am new take part in so i don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer for your question is "Watch out your variable's names!" Look - you've created 2 Handlers - named "mhandle" and "handle". You want to parse message in Handler named "mhandle", but in your Thread send it to "handle", which is doing nothing from your code.
Hope it will help if you still trying to find the answer.